# How can I give SqlException in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sqlexception, unique-key

I have `SqlException` error in `cnt.SaveChanges()` method.
That error is true but I want to give a message box for that error. 
How can I do that ?

I tried try catch. But it didn't work true.

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Bu satırı sil !!!", "Evet", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
  if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow != null)
  {
    int ware_id = (int)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["WAREHOUSE_ID"].Value;
    var itemToRemove = cnt.WAREHOUSEs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.WAREHOUSE_ID == ware_id);

    if (itemToRemove != null)
    {
      cnt.WAREHOUSEs.Remove(itemToRemove);
      cnt.SaveChanges();
      Listele();
    }
  }
}

 if (MessageBox.Show("Bu satırı sil !!!", "Evet", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
  if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow != null)
  {
    int ware_id = (int)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["WAREHOUSE_ID"].Value;
    var itemToRemove = cnt.WAREHOUSEs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.WAREHOUSE_ID == ware_id);

    if (itemToRemove != null)
    {
      cnt.WAREHOUSEs.Remove(itemToRemove);
  try{
      cnt.SaveChanges();
      Listele();
     }
  catch(Exception)
     {
    MessageBox.Show("Couldn't Delete");
     }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: make use of `try..catch` and display custom message from the catch block

Comment: Please show your *try-catch* attempt and describe why the result wasn't what you expected.

Comment: @HəsənCəfərov programme gives error at cnt.SaveChanges(); Listele method doesn't execute

Comment: You need to put a try/catch block inside here. And you need to do more than just display an error in a message box. You need to log it somewhere so you know that it happened and what the error is.

Comment: @sujithkarivelil I tried this.(Check code again)

Comment: @SeanLange check code again please

Comment: @Filburt can you check the code again please ?

Comment: @SemihŞEN: And what is the issue with the updated code?

Comment: You should have all of your code inside a try/catch. And honestly you have an anti-pattern here. You capture an error and give a meaningless message to the user. You don't have a clue that an error happened and have no way to debug it because you lose all those details once you leave the catch block. Handling errors properly is crucial. You are off to a good start but is only the first step in doing this the right way.

Comment: @sujithkarivelil after first delete try I can not delete any row.

Comment: I think you need something like this `catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show("could not delete" + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message); } ` But  I recommend reading up on exception handling and add some logging to your application